# Struts2: Is there a way that checkbox directly links to action class when checkbox is checked?

Tags: struts2

For eg:

```html
<s:checkbox name="checkMe" fieldValue="true" label="Check Me for testing" action="someactionclass"/>
```

when checkbox is selected, the control is not redirecting to the particular action class method.

Comment: You could set a validation for this in your action class. Using the validation to see if the value has been filled in: Going back to the original form if it hasn't is pretty much what you're trying to do here.

Comment: You could do this with javascript.

Comment: You *must* do this with JavaScript.

Comment: You have to do it with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You must use JavaScript for this problem and toggle the action of the form according to the change event of the checkbox.

Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$('#checkBoxId').change(function() {
     if(this.checked) {
         // do something when checked, change action.
     } else {
         // do something else
     }
});
```